# HashMap null value issue

Tags: java

What is the difference between both of result.

1. When I've null value with key
2. When key itself is not exist

In above both condition result is null. So how can i identify my key value

```
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put(1,null);
System.out.println(map.get(1));
System.out.println(map.get(2));
```

Answer:

```
null

null
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Key existence check in HashMap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626752/key-existence-check-in-hashmap)

Answer (score 9):

While `get` returns the same result for `null` value and non-existing key, `containsKey` doesn't:

`map.containsKey(1)` would return `true`.

`map.containsKey(2)` would return `false`.

In addition, if you iterate over the keys of the `Map` (using `keySet()`), `1` will be there and `2` won't.

Answer (score 0):

Hashmap returns null if no `Value` is mapped to the key. So this can be solved by your code also:

```
if( map.get(1) != null ){
     //
}
```

[Reference Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Comment: This suggestion doesn't help the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Make a check for if the value is null to avoid the null prints.

pseudo code:

```
//For inputting
if(object != null){
   map.put(1, object);
}
//For getting the value
if(value != null){
     map.get(value)
  }
```