# Creating a method to check if a value exists in a generic HashMap in Java?

Tags: java, class, dictionary, generics, hashmap

I was trying to create a generic method for checking if an item exists within a HashMap. Simple enough concept, but Java does not like what I'm trying to do. Is this even possible? This was my attempt.

```
private static boolean inMap(String file, HashMap<String, Object> map) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey().equals(file)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is called in the following section of code:

```
private static Map<String, String> files = new HashMap();
private static Map<String, BufferedImage> images = new HashMap();
private static Map<String, Texture> textures = new HashMap();
private static Map<String, Model> models = new HashMap();

public static TexturedModel loadOBJModel(String file) {
    if (inMap(file, files)) ...
}

public static Texture loadTexture(String file) {
    if (inMap(file, textures)) ...
}
```

I wanted this method to be generic for saving code and simplicity, as i have 4 different HashMaps to check. All of them are `String` keys, but they are all of different Value types as shown above.

If there is any way to make this generic, any help is welcome!

Comment: Why can't you use `files.containsKey('someStringKey');` and likewise for others?

Comment: @Raf post as answer please

Comment: There already is a question on how to use `Hashmap.containsKey()` see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626752/key-existence-check-in-hashmap

Comment: Are you actually looking to see if has a key? The way I read your question I thought you were looking to see if the map contains a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you re-inventing the wheel? `Map` has `containsKey()` which does exactly as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make use of [`Map.get(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get-java.lang.Object-) here, and the fact that it will return null if the key doesn't exist.

```
public static boolean contains(Map<?, ?> inMap, Object key) {
    return inMap.get(key) == null;
}
```

This will also take advantage of the O(1) access time of hashmaps without relying on an O(n) loop over entries.

Comment: You don't need to use `.get()`, the `containsKey()` is enough and is `O(1)`

Comment: Perfect, thank you. works perfectly!

Comment: @Raf post as answer, didn't even know this exists.

Answer (score 1):

you can write generic method using `T` type parameter, you can use this method for all different types of `HashMap`

```
public static <T> boolean contains(String file, T a) {
    return a.keySet().contains(file); //or a.containsKey(file);

}
```