# Searching through a collection of an array list pair

Tags: java, if-statement, collections, arraylist, iterator

I am trying to search through a collection of an ArrayList if pairs. What I want to be able to do, is to go through the collection and find the first value in a pair and return the second value of that pair. The problem I am having is that the check I have to find the first value doesn't seem to be working, so every time I search, I end up returning null. I know that the problem exists with my if statement, but I cannot seem to sort out what it is I am doing wrong. Since this is a homework assignment, I can't show all the code to my pair class, or my pair list class, but I can show you the method I have for searching the first value:

```
public S findFirst(F firstValue) {
    Iterator<Pair> myIter = this.iterator();
    S tmp2 = null;
    while (myIter.hasNext()) {
        Pair tmp1 = myIter.next();
        if (tmp1.getFirst() == firstCall) {
            tmp2 = (S) tmp1.getSecond();
        }
    }
    return tmp2;
}
```

If I throw in an else statement that just calls what I am attempting to do in my if check, like this:

```
else{
           tmp2 = (S) tmp1.getSecond(); 
        }
```

then whenever I test for the first value, I get the second value, so I know I am at least on the correct path, but I am assuming that I am doing something wrong with what I am checking for in my if statement. Does anyone know how I can correctly do this, (and please bear in mind that this is homework, so a guide to how to figure this out is far more valuable to me than just some random answer, I want to learn, not just be given an answer) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it possible for you to use a `HashMap` instead of an `ArrayList` ?  This is the sort of thing they're designed for.

Comment: I beg you not to use `==` to compare Strings.

Comment: @ David, no, it has to be an arraylist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `==` to compare objects. Override and use `equals()`.

Comment: You're correct. I didn't even think about that, I was too busy just trying to make the comparison, which is sad because I used the .equals in my last assignment and actually argued with someone over why its smarter to use that over the equals sign. I have made the change and now everything works perfect. Thank you so much.

Comment: Of course I have now realized a new problem, I can only search through the last entry in the collection, so if I add a pair into the collection of say, one and two, and then another pair of three and four, if I use this method to find one, I get null, the fun never ends...

Answer (score 2):

I think

```
if (tmp1.getFirst() == firstCall)
```

should probably say

```
if (tmp1.getFirst().equals(firstValue))
```

The important difference is that == checks whether two expressions refer to the exact same object.  You're more interested in knowing whether your two expressions actually refer to objects that are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (tmp1.getFirst().equals(firstValue))
```

instead of

```
if (tmp1.getFirst() == firstCall)
```

Also you can override your own equals method.

You should never use `==` to compare objects.

Check [How to compare two java objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069106/how-to-compare-two-java-objects)

Answer (score 0):

What Matt says, (don't use `==` ) but I think a bigger problem is that you don't return the 'first' encounter.... your `if` statement should look like:

```
public S findFirst(F firstValue) {
    Iterator<Pair> myIter = this.iterator();
    while (myIter.hasNext()) {
        Pair tmp1 = myIter.next();
        if (firstValue.equals(tmp1.getFirst())) {
            return (S) tmp1.getSecond();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```