# Arrays.sort (Comparator) - Java 6 vs Java 7

Tags: java, java-7, java-6

```
import java.util.Comparator;
public class CompareTester {
int i;
public static class Inside implements Comparator<CompareTester> {
    @Override
    public int compare(CompareTester o1, CompareTester o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(o1.i - o2.i);
        return 0;
}}}

public class CompareTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CompareTester j = new CompareTester();
    j.i = 3;
    CompareTester k = new CompareTester();
    k.i = 5;
    CompareTester l = new CompareTester();
    l.i = 7;
    CompareTester[] numbers = { j, k, l };
    Arrays.sort(numbers, new CompareTester.Inside());
}}
```

These are two classes that are giving two different results in CompareTester class when ran in Java 6  and Java 7.

Is there any different kind of implementation that has been introduced in Java7 for Comparator?

Comment: return 0 in `compare` would mean objects are the same for such purpose so the order depends if the algorithm is `stable` or not

Comment: Your compare tester returns everything is equal. This isn't a good idea, or a good test.

Comment: Why is your `Comparator` always return `0`?

Comment: Here I am just considering the issue why the "compare" method in "CompareTester" class is taking two different parameters (o1 and o2) for Java 6  and Java7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from a [different sorting algorithm](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6804124), which is only relevant internally, there are no difference between the final result of `Array.sort(E, Comparator)`. So, no, there is not difference "introduced in Java7 for Comparator".

Just change your implementation to

```
import java.util.Comparator;
public class CompareTester {
    int i;
    public static class Inside implements Comparator<CompareTester> {
        @Override
        public int compare(CompareTester o1, CompareTester o2) {
            return o1.i - o2.i;
        }
    }
}
```

and compare the final resulting array instead and you'll see that there is no difference between Java 6 and 7.

#### Edit

If you want to avoid using a `Comparator`, then make your `CompareTester` class implement [`Comparable<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) instead (Java 7 doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html));

```
import java.lang.Comparable;
public class CompareTester implements Comparable<CompareTester> {
    int i;

    public int compareTo(CompareTester o) {
        return this.i - o.i;
    }
}
```

Then, you don't need anything special with `Array.sort` :

```
Arrays.sort(numbers);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here different sorting algorithm is irrelevant because I am just using integers. But in actual application code I am using objects which I have to override compare method to compare the objects. This is causing an issue.

Comment: If you're comparing two `Object`s, as in `obj1 == obj2`, then take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069106/how-to-compare-two-java-objects); you should override `.equals` and `.hashCode`. For sorting, then implementing the `Comparable<T>` interface is the correct way to go.

Answer (score 4):

Java 7 uses TimSort, Java 6 used MergeSort. Your comparator always returns 0 which breaks the [Comparable Contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and TimSort is picking up on that.

To fix the code you really need to address that. If you really want to use the old sort algorithm then compile with `-Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true`