# When do we say Object1 .equals(Object2) is true?

Tags: java, object, equals

I have below code written:

```
public class Test{
    int a;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Test t1 = new Test();
        Test t2 = new Test();
        if(!t1.equals(t2))
            System.out.println("They're not equal");
        if(t1 instanceof Test)
            System.out.println("True");
    }
}
```

And here is the **Output**:

```
They're not equal
True
```

I even tried to assign the same value to instance variable `'a'` of both these objects, like below,

```
t1.a = 10;
t2.a = 10;
```

Still the same output.

May I know when the `t1.equals(t2)` will return **True**?
How does the `equals()` method work on objects?

Comment: override the equals method provided by default by the Object class

Comment: You need to override the methods `equal()` and `hashCode()`(optional) to achieve this

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the instance method , please try reading about Object Equality in Java, it would clear all your doubts

Comment: My 2 cents: If you do `Test t1 = new Test(); Test t2 = t1;` then `t1.equals(t2)` will return true.

Comment: refer this : http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/09/04/the-3-things-you-should-know-about-hashcode/

Comment: also this : http://java67.blogspot.in/2013/04/example-of-overriding-equals-hashcode-compareTo-java-method.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare two objects with .equals() and == operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387742/compare-two-objects-with-equals-and-operator)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare two java objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069106/how-to-compare-two-java-objects)

Answer (score 2):

By default, calling `equals` execute the `equals` method of `Object` class, which returns true only when you are comparing an instance to itself.

You can override this method in other classes, so that `equals` would return true when the properties of both objects are equal.

For example :

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other)
{
    if (other == null)
        return false;
    if (other instance of Test) {
        Test t = (test) other;
        return this.a == t.a;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Adding this method to your `Test` class would change the result of `t1.equals(t2)` to `true`.

Comment: Oh, got it now. I thought equals() would check if 2 different objects are identical or not.

Comment: @TouhidK. It would, but you have to define what identical means for your specific class.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Object.equals(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) Javadoc says (in part),

> Indicates whether some other object is "equal to" this one.
>
> The equals method implements an equivalence relation on non-null object references:
>
> - It is reflexive: for any non-null reference value x, x.equals(x) should return true.
> - It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true.
> - It is transitive: for any non-null reference values x, y, and z, if x.equals(y) returns true and y.equals(z) returns true, then x.equals(z) should return true.
> - It is consistent: for any non-null reference values x and y, multiple invocations of x.equals(y) consistently return true or consistently return false, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the objects is modified.
> - For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false.

For your code you could override `equals` like

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Test) {
        return ((Test) o).a == a;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The default implementation of Object.equals treats two objects as equal only if they are exactly the same object, not just the same contents but the same reference.

Objects can have different implementations of equals, but you must program them explicitly: if you want to check that all fields are equal, you must actually write an equals implementation that checks that.