# Search Algorithm Causing StackOverFlowError

Tags: java, stack, depth-first-search

I am using what is known as a Depth First Search to solve a maze using my own Stack created class for an assignment. The reason I believe I am getting this error is because my program is never meeting the `finishSpot` condition. I have used the debugger and it looks like it is infinitely stuck at the Point before the `finishSpot`. My logic seems to be mostly correct except until the point where my maze solver tries to finish the maze, so i just need help meeting that last condition that is causing my program to crash.

This is a sample maze where 's' is start and 'f' is finish and '*' is wall.

```
*****
*s* *
* * *
*  f*
*****
```

This is my Main which uses my LinkedStack class which I can post if needed.

```
//Creates a Stack and determines the start and endpoints.
public static void solveDFS( char [][] maze ){
    LinkedStack stack = new LinkedStack();
    Point currentSpot = findPoint( maze,'s' );
    Point finishSpot = findPoint( maze, 'f' );
    findPath( maze,currentSpot, finishSpot,stack );  
}
//Finds a point by searching for a char.
private static Point findPoint( char [][] maze, char c ) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < maze.length; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < maze[i].length; j++ ) {
            if ( maze[i][j] == c ) {
                return new Point(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
//Search algorithm looks for all neighbor locations
private static boolean findPath( char [][] maze, Point currentSpot, Point finishSpot, LinkedStack stack ){
    boolean hasSolution = false;
    stack.push(currentSpot);

    while( currentSpot != finishSpot && !stack.isEmpty() ){
        // Checks Right
        if( currentSpot.x < maze.length ){
            if( maze[currentSpot.x + 1][currentSpot.y] == ' '){
                stack.push(new Point( currentSpot.x + 1, currentSpot.y ));
            }
        }
        // Checks Left
        if( currentSpot.x > 0 ){
            if( maze[currentSpot.x - 1][currentSpot.y] == ' '){
                stack.push(new Point( currentSpot.x - 1, currentSpot.y ));
            }
        }
        // Checks Up
        if( currentSpot.y > 0 ){
            if( maze[currentSpot.x][currentSpot.y - 1] == ' ' ){
                stack.push(new Point( currentSpot.x, currentSpot.y - 1));
            }
        }
        // Checks Down
        if( currentSpot.y < maze[currentSpot.x].length ){
            if( maze[currentSpot.x][currentSpot.y + 1] == ' '){
                stack.push(new Point( currentSpot.x, currentSpot.y + 1));
            }
        }
        // Checks Finish (My program never meets this condition help!)
        if( currentSpot == finishSpot ){
            printMaze(maze);
            hasSolution = true;
        }
        currentSpot = stack.pop();
        findPath( maze, currentSpot, finishSpot, stack );
    }   
    return hasSolution;
}
```

Comment: `if( currentSpot == finishSpot )` ... I don't think you should use `==` here. Use `if( currentSpot.equals(finishSpot) )` instead and override `equals` and `hashCode` in the `Point` class.

Comment: why to use stack instead of recursion?

Comment: @mangusta It is for an assignment which I am required to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Following conditions will never be true at the same time in your code

```
while( currentSpot != finishSpot && !stack.isEmpty() ){
    ...
    if( currentSpot == finishSpot ){
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't think you can compare The `Points` variables like that.
Try to override the method `equals`

Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069106/how-to-compare-two-java-objects)