# Compare two gson converted objects in java

Tags: android, json, gson, android-volley

I want to compare whether the keys of two Gson converted objects are the same.

Example:
 I have one JSON object in a file ***customer.json*** which is stored locally:

```
{
  name:"John",
  age:25
}
```

There is an API which gives the same JSON data from a custom volley request which I am converting to a `Customer` POJO.

Now I want to determine whether the JSON data stored locally and the JSON data received from the API are the same.

I am reading the JSON file and converting it to a `Customer` as follows:

```
InputStream is = getContext().getResources().openRawResource(
    R.raw.customerjson);
Gson gson = new Gson();
Reader reader = null;
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
Customer customerLocal = gson.fromJson(reader, Customer.class);
```

Now I have both of the converted `Customer` objects (`customerLocal` and `customerServer`).

Everything is working fine; the problem is that I don't know how to compare the two Gson converted objects. Note that I want to compare only the keys (i.e. the variable name in the POJO, not the value).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: why don't you compare in string form??

Comment: I thought this.But volley response will give me the converted pojo not string. And more over we are using custom volley request which is all over the project so cannot change the custom request and response

Comment: By pojo do you mean to say bean object??

Comment: Plain Old Java Object - POJO

Comment: Simply Iterate over the JSON object and compare the keys. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151619/java-iterate-over-jsonobject

Comment: Anyway, I think you missed the conversion to a json string after you read the response data from InputStream. 
`BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }` Then `sb.toString();` to find the string.

Comment: gson.fromJson(reader, Customer.class); will convert from  reader to string and then Customer class

Comment: Shouldn't it just be a java object comparison once you have both Customer objects (customerLocal and customerServer)? Something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069106/how-to-compare-two-java-objects by provideing your own implementation of equals()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it. By converting the gson converted object back to json like below

```
JSONObject serverJsonObject = new JSONObject(gson.toJson(customerResponse));
```

Then compared serverJsonObect with locally stored json object with 
***assertJsonEquals*** method from [JsonUnit Library](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit)

My test cases are working fine now.