# Java type parameter in static method compile time

Tags: java, generics, types, compile-time

I'm writing universal compare utility, it should be type safe as possible. Idea is to prevent comparing of different class Objects. For example this works OK:

```
UtilityClazz.<String>compare("dd", 1); //OK - compile time error
```

Is there more elegant way to call Utility class, that has type parameter. This below is not OK because it will compare Date and int

```
compare(SomeObject.getDate(), 1); //NOT OK - compiles OK no type is passed
```

Method Code:

```
public static<T> int compare(T value1, T value2) {
    if (value1 instanceof Time && value2 instanceof Time) {
        return DateComparator.compareTimes((Time) value1, (Time) value2);
    } else if (value1 instanceof Date && value2 instanceof Date) {
        return DateComparator.compareDates((Date) value1, (Date) value2);
    } else if (value1 instanceof Number && value2 instanceof Number) {
        return NumberUtility.compare((Number) value1, (Number) value2);
    } else {
        //....
        return 0;
    }

}
```

}

How to make method call elegant as possible ?

Comment: This answer could be useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069106/how-to-compare-two-java-objects

Comment: first remove that **<string>** from _UtilityClazz.<String>compare("dd", 1);_

Comment: Refer to https://github.com/jeevatkm/generic-repo/blob/master/genericComparator/src/main/java/com/myjeeva/comparator/GenericComparator.java

Comment: Question is more about how would you do it then about generics.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it easier with method overload rather than with generics:

```
public static int compare(Time value1, Time value2) {
   return DateComparator.compareTimes(value1, value2);
}

public static int compare(Number value1, Number value2) {
   return NumberUtility.compare(value1, value2);
}
```

This eliminates unnecessary `instanceof` checks and gives some compile time type guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

This one you checked generic type as `String`, and doesnt compile because 1 is not `String`:

```
UtilityClazz.<String>compare("dd", 1);
```

but below you dont check generic type, and automatically compiler checks it as `Object`, and `Object` type is passed.

```
compare(SomeObject.getDate(), 1);
```

You must add `Object` case to your compare method

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a serie of `if`, you can make a map which associates a class to its comparator: `Map<Class<?>,Comparator<?>>`. The class is available through the `getClass()` method.

If you want to handle polymorphism, then you would have to call `getSuperclass()` on each object until you find a common ancestor.