# My JUnit Test Fails

Tags: java, junit

Why does this fail the JUnit Test. I have a class called Complex for Complex Numbers with the Constructor accepting 2 parameters real and imaginary which looks like this

```
Public Complex(double real, double imaginary) {
    this.real=real;
    this.imagine=imagine;
}
```

And then I have a method for adding to it called add like this

```
Public Complex add (Complex other) {
    double temporaryReal = real + other.real;
    double temporaryImagine = Imagine + other.Imagine;
    return new Complex(temporaryReal, tempImagine);
}
```

I have a test class set up for testing the method. It looks like this

```
public void testAdd() {
    Complex other = new Complex(15, 30);
    Complex newComplex = new Complex(15, 30);

    assertTrue( myComplex.add(other) == newComplex );
}
```

If I put in the correct parameters, the JUnit test should pass. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: is `Imagine` spelled with uppercase `I` when you add? and in the constructor you pass `imaginary` but the variable is `imagine`. And what is `myComplex`? unless it is zero your assert will be false. And comparison of objects is not done with `==`. So many potential problems here...

Comment: This seems to have many problems with variable declarations and initializations. Specially with cases..

Answer (score 2):

`myComplex.add(other)` returns an object reference. `newComplex` is also an object reference, which refers to another object. So when you say `myComplex.add(other) == newComplex` you are trying to check if the two references are the same, which is not.

If you want to compare the two objects, you need to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods from the base class `Object`. Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069106/how-to-compare-two-java-objects#16069158) to find out how to do that.