# How to implement a hash function for a point on a grid

Tags: java, hash

I need a hash function to overide the hashCode() method from the object class.

I have a Point class that represents a point on coordinate grid. The instance variables are               double x, y;

I also have methods

```
public int getX(){
 return Math.round(x);
}

public int getY(){
   Math.round(y);
}
```

How can I create a hash function that will return an integer?
Would a simply put

```
return Math.round(getX()/getY());
```

work?

Comment: The aim of a hash function is to uniformly distribute values between 0 and 2^32 - 1.  Does your function do that?

Comment: Well how are you defining equality, first? Why do you have `double` variables if you're rounding in the getters? Are they actually intended to be more than integers, usefully?

Comment: There are going to be a lot of hash collisions if you do it this way... For example, 6/3 = 2 and 4/2 = 2;

Answer (score 1):

Your IDE most likely has a utility to generate hash code and equals for you, look under the source or insert code menus.

All you need to do though is `return getX()+31*getY()`;

See this question and answer for more detailed discussion on the theory of hash codes:

[Best implementation for hashCode method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113511/hash-code-implementation)