# Can I use hashcode of class member for class?

Tags: java, hashcode, class-members

I have class with final String as unique ID. Of course I want to override equals so comparison is based on ID only. Is it correct practice then to just return hash code of ID, like below?

```
class ItemSpec{
    final String name;

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if(o != null && o instanceof ItemSpec){
            return name.equalsIgnoreCase(((ItemSpec)o).name);
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
         if(name == null){
             return 0;
         } else{
             return name.hashCode();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that your `equals` method assumes that `name` isn't null, but your `hashCode` method assumes that it might be. Which is it?

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry, I noticed that after adding. Edited.

Comment: Can't see the edit. Still can't be null in equals.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not if your equals is case insensitive. You could have two `ItemSpec` coming out as equal but with different hash codes. That breaks the most crucial requirement of a hash code.

Your `equals` has to agree with your `hashCode`. So if you are going to compare them case insensitively, you have to write your `hashCode` case insensitively.

```
@Override
public int hashCode(){
     if (name == null){
         return 0;
     } else{
         return name.toLowerCase().hashCode();
     }
}
```

Also your `hashCode` method implies that `name` could be null. If so, you should null-check it in your `equals` method as well.

Comment: Can't there be a case where `a.equalsIgnoreCase(b)` but `a.toLowerCase().equals(b.toLowerCase())` is false?

Comment: Good catch, but wanted to point out the same as assylias: The conversion may open the door for a locale-specific and unicode-related hassle...

Comment: Well I realised that myself and edited, but you sir are just too fast for me ;)

Comment: If there is a case where `equalsIgnoreCase` is coarser than `toLowerCase`, then I guess the best way to be certain they match up is to use `a.toLowerCase().equals(b.toLowerCase())` in the `equals` method.

Answer (score -1):

I dont see any problem with your approach.

But, I've often seen the following implementation:

```
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = super.hashCode();
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    return result;
}
```

Update:
Here is a link with a better explanation:
[Best implementation for hashCode method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113511/hash-code-implementation)

Comment: That looks like auto-generated code and does not do much apart from increasing the computation time...

Comment: You can't incorporate `super.hashCode` into your hashcode if you're not requiring `super.equals` in your equals method. Otherwise two equal objects may get different hashcodes.

Comment: I took this code from my project. I am not 100% certain, if I did it manually, or it was Eclipse generated. But I did look at the most common approach to implement hashCode, and this was most common approach in my view.

Comment: It was popularised in Joshua Bloch's book, 'Effective Java'.  There are variants of it, and quite a lot of the JDK libraries use it.  For example Arrays.hashCode.  It is done to spread out the hashCodes over the limited range, and to try to reduce pooling/hotspots within the hashed range.  Which all affect the performance of hashmaps and the like.