# Java: Is it OK to implement hashCode and equals for a third-party class?

Tags: java, jaxb, equals, hashcode

Assume we have the following class:

```
public class SingleElementRefType
{

    protected JAXBElement<SequenceType> sequence;

    // ...
}
```

It contains the `sequence` field of type [`JAXBElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBElement.html).

[`JAXBElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBElement.html) is a third-party class (standard API, actually), which is in essence a pure value class, but it for some reason does not implement `hashCode` and `equals` methods.

From my point of view, these methods are absolutely reasonable there.

I would like to implement `equals` and `hashCode` methods for `SingleElementRefType` as well as `SequenceType` so that I could do a deep comparison of this values. But `JAXBElement` stands in the way.

Since I can't extend `JAXBElement`, my idea was to integrate `hashCode` and `equals` into the aggregating class (`SingleElementRefType` here):

```
JAXBElement<SequenceType> theSequence;
theSequence = this.getSequence();

final QName theSequenceName = theSequence.getName();
currentHashCode = ((currentHashCode* 37) +
    ((theSequenceName!= null)?theSequenceName.hashCode(): 0));

final Object theSequenceValue = theSequence.getValue();
currentHashCode = ((currentHashCode* 37) +
    ((theSequenceValue!= null)?theSequenceValue.hashCode(): 0));
```

But then I had second thoughts if I'm not breaking some convention or rule here.

Are there any dangers of implementing `hashCode` and `equals` for third-party classes in my aggregating classes?

*Update:* for certain reasons my code may not have further runtime dependencies. So I can't use Guava or `commons-lang` here.

Comment: It is a perfectly reasonable thing to do if you need it; if you use Guava, you may consider using an `Equivalence`, see [here](http://javachannel.org/posts/guavas-equivalence-strategy-for-equalshashcode/).

Comment: @fge Can't use Guava here - my code must not have further runtime dependencies. But a good tip, I'll check the concept.

Comment: Couldn't the containing class (I assume that this would be one that represents another XML element) take care of equals and hashCode simply by bypassing the JAXBElement? I do know that xjc doesn't include these methods, but a plugin could, and so could a hand-written class where an element needs the JAXBElement wrapper.

Comment: @laune We're writing an XJC plugin right now. That's where the question come from. We could generate code for `JAXBElement`s but won't we break anything with it? I think not, but better ask...

Comment: Then do not include the tag name in the equals and hashCode computations. It's pointless. If the containing class's equals is being called, and we've bypassed the is-it-the-same-class stage we have objects of the same type, and then the name must be equal, so it's not necessary to consider.

Comment: Assume that there is an equals and a hashCode in JAXBElement, and both consider all attributes of that class. Would you call this equals for a "deep comparison"? What if their QName namespaces differ, everything else being equal? Do you intend to compare XML documents or Java object hierarchies?

Comment: @laune *"then the name must be equal"* - why so? You can get different names in `@XmlElementRef` property.

Comment: @laune *"Would you call this equals for a "deep comparison"?"* - yes. *"What if their QName namespaces differ, everything else being equal?"* - then they're different.

Comment: Your last "yes" in your last comment indicates that you want to compare XML documents and not just object contents.

Comment: "different names in @XmlElementRef" Indeed. This would make two references to equal Java objects that happen to be in differently tagged XML elements not equal?!?

Comment: @laune Please join the discussion on GitHub: https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/issues/11

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly reasonable to override the hashCode and equals method of your model class. While overriding them, java specifies a list of contracts to be followed.

**For equals,**

- reflexive [x.equals(x) = true]
- symmetric[x.equals(y)=true, then (y.equals(x)==true) ]
- transitive [x.equals(y)==true && y.equals(z)==true, then x.equals(z)==true]
- consistent
- ‘non-nullity’ [x.equals(null)==false]

**For hashCode,**

- consistency : return same integer for the same object
- if (o1.equals(o2), then o1.hashcode == o2.hashcode)
- not viceversa

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113511/best-implementation-for-hashcode-method?rq=1) can provide you insight into best practices to be followed while overriding hashCode().

And for overriding equals follow these practices :

- Use == to check if the argument is a reference to this object
- Use instanceof operator to check if the argument has the correct type
- Cast the argument to the correct type
- For each “significant” field in the class, check if that field of the argument matches the corresponding field of this object

A way you can make sure that your overridden hashCode and equals method are effectively following the contracts will be to test them using Junits.
Need of overriding hashCode and equals will be more evident when, at some point of time, have to use your model class in a hash based collection, say a hashmap or hashset.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The author, judging by their SO reputation, is not asking for a tutorial on equals and hashCode.

Comment: i didnt notice that! then it should be so!