# Is there any reference source on Android Pair's hashCode implementation, which uses XOR operator

Tags: java, android

When I look at "old" version of Android Pair's `hashCode`, its implementation is following text in

Josh Bloch's Effective Java - [Best implementation for hashCode method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113511/hash-code-implementation)

## ["Old" Pair.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/d4a1d2e14297a3387fdb5761090961e714370492/core/java/android/util/Pair.java#L60)

```
/**
 * Compute a hash code using the hash codes of the underlying objects
 * @return a hashcode of the Pair
 */
public int hashCode() {
    int result = 17;
    result = 31 * result + first.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + second.hashCode();
    return result;
}
```

However, when I look at "latest" version of Android Pair's `hashCode`, it looks like this

## ["New" Pair.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/util/Pair.java#L64)

```
/**
 * Compute a hash code using the hash codes of the underlying objects
 *
 * @return a hashcode of the Pair
 */
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return (first == null ? 0 : first.hashCode()) ^ (second == null ? 0 : second.hashCode());
}
```

May I know, is there any reference source, on why `XOR` operator is being used? I thought we shouldn't violate Josh Bloch's teaching :) ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why the author moved from the prime number technique to the XOR technique, but the change was motivated by needing to support `null` values in the `Pair` class. See this commit: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/162fabbcf81157fddab1c38de09bdabaff8c068a#diff-e73c0c4c169861c96264276ecce62169. In theory, the implementation could have used the old version if neither object is `null` but if either is, then the hashCode becomes that of the non-null component of the pair (or `0` if both are null).