# Getting duplicate Elements using HashSet

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashset

I am getting duplicate entries into ListView using ArrayList to populate and HashSet to remove duplicate elements, but still getting duplicate values like this:

```
Delhi
Mumbai
Delhi
Mumbai
```

Here is my code which i am using to parse JSON data into List and to remove duplicate entries

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<Destination> destinationArrayList;    
    MainAdapter adapter;
    Destination destination;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        destinationArrayList = new ArrayList<Destination>();

        new JSONAsyncTask().execute("my api link");

        Set<Destination> hashset = new HashSet<>(); 
        hashset.addAll(destinationArrayList); 
        destinationArrayList.clear(); 
        destinationArrayList.addAll(hashset);

        ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new MainAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, destinationArrayList);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), destinationArrayList.get(position).getTitle().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                
            }
        });

    }


    class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {

                //------------------>>
                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                    JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("data");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                        destination = new Destination();

                        destination.setCity(object.getString("city"));

                        destinationArrayList.add(destination);

                    }
                    return true;
                }

                //------------------>>

            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            dialog.cancel();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if(result == false)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

}
```

And when i use this, even `not getting single record` into ListView:

```
destinationArrayList = new ArrayList<Destination>();

        new JSONAsyncTask().execute("my api url");

        System.out.println("size of Arraylist with duplicates: " + destinationArrayList.size());

        System.out.println(destinationArrayList);

        HashSet<Destination> listToSet = new HashSet<Destination>(destinationArrayList);

        ArrayList<Destination> listWithoutDuplicates = new ArrayList<Destination>(listToSet);
        System.out.println("size of ArrayList without duplicates: " + listToSet.size());

        System.out.println(listWithoutDuplicates);
```

**Destination.java**

```
public class Destination {

    private String city;
    ..............

    public Destination() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Destination(String city) {
        super();
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the `Destination` class definition, please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are putting the `Custom objects` to the HashSet so it is not eliminating duplicates. You need to override the `equals` and `hashCode` for the Destination object. Then it works fine.

```
class Destination {

    private String city;

    public Destination() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Destination(String city) {
        super();
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Destination that = (Destination) o;

        if (city != null ? !city.equals(that.city) : that.city != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return city != null ? city.hashCode() : 0;
    }
}
```

place this code in on postExecute() method in the AsynTask then it shows the all the elements in the list.

```
 Set<Destination> hashset = new HashSet<>(); 
        hashset.addAll(destinationArrayList); 
        destinationArrayList.clear(); 
        destinationArrayList.addAll(hashset);

        ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new MainAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, destinationArrayList);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: tried your way updated Destination java class but yet not done

Comment: @Oreo you need to set values after AsynTask completed.

Comment: @Oreo if you needed sorting implement comparable and use Collections.sort(list); and u r use using AsyncTask so not possible to put your code in onCreate().

Answer (score 0):

The de-duplication using the `Set` is not working since, given your current `Destination` class definition, instances of `Destination` that have the same `city` value are not considered equal.

Try [overriding .equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java) in your `Destination` class....

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that the hash set could not recognize two pairs of `Destination` objects as equal no matter that they have only one property `City`.

To compare two objects you would need to override the super method `equals` and as well your object is being used into a hash table, you would need also to override `hashCode`

There are some proven methods which will avoid collisions on hashes that you could use in `hashCode`. One of them is [Best implementation for hashCode method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113511/best-implementation-for-hashcode-method)

Answer (score 0):

Your Destination class should have equals() and hashCode() methods to eliminate duplicate records aganist to city. The following code which include the methods can solve your problem :

```
public class Destination {

    private String city;
    ..............

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((city == null) ? 0 : city.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Destination other = (Destination) obj;
        if (city == null) {
            if (other.city != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!city.equals(other.city))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```