# Java HashSet contains returns false, even with overridden equals() and hashCode()

Tags: java, equals, contains, hashcode, hashset

I initialize the HashSet like this:

```
private HashSet<Rule> ruleTable = new HashSet<Rule>();
```

The `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods of my `TcpRule` object (sub-class of abstract class `Rule`) look like this:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    // Ignore source Port for now
    return (this.getSrcPool() + ":" + this.getDstPool() + ":" + this.getProtocol() + ":" + this.dstTcp).hashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof TcpRule))
        return false;
    if (obj == this)
        return true;

    TcpRule r = (TcpRule) obj;
    return (this.getSrcPool().equals(r.getSrcPool()) && this.getDstPool().equals(r.getDstPool()) && this.getProtocol().equals(r.getProtocol()) && this.getSrcTcp() == r.getSrcTcp() && this.getDstTcp() == r.getDstTcp());
}
```

I have even written a simple unit test, which does not give any error:

```
@Test
public void equalsTest() {
    Pool srcPool = new Pool("PROXY");
    Pool dstPool = new Pool("WEB");
    int srcTcp = 54321;
    int dstTcp = 80;

    TcpRule r1 = new TcpRule(srcPool, dstPool, srcTcp, dstTcp);
    TcpRule r2 = r1;
    assert r1.equals(r2);

    TcpRule r3 = new TcpRule(srcPool, dstPool, srcTcp, dstTcp);
    TcpRule r4 = new TcpRule(srcPool, dstPool, srcTcp, dstTcp);
    assert r3.equals(r4);
}

@Test
public void hashCodeTest() {
    Pool srcPool = new Pool("PROXY");
    Pool dstPool = new Pool("WEB");
    int srcTcp = 54321;
    int dstTcp = 80;

    TcpRule r1 = new TcpRule(srcPool, dstPool, srcTcp, dstTcp);
    TcpRule r2 = new TcpRule(srcPool, dstPool, srcTcp, dstTcp);
    assert r1.hashCode() == r2.hashCode();

    HashSet<Rule> rules = new HashSet<Rule>();
    rules.add(r1);
    assert rules.contains(r1);

    assert rules.contains(r2);
}
```

In my application, I have an `add()` method where I simply add a `Rule` object to the `HashSet`:

```
@Override
public void add(Rule rule) {
    ruleTable.add(rule);
}
```

In another method, I check if a rule exists in the `HashSet`:

```
    @Override
public boolean isPermittedTcp(IpAddress sourceAddress, IpAddress destinationAddress, short srcTcp, short dstTcp) {
    Pool sourcePool = poolService.getPool(new Host(sourceAddress));
    Pool destinationPool = poolService.getPool(new Host(destinationAddress));
    Rule r = new TcpRule(sourcePool, destinationPool, srcTcp, dstTcp);
    log.info("Checking: " + r.toString());
    log.info("Hash-Code: " + r.hashCode());
    log.info("Hashes in ruleTable:");
    for(Rule rT : ruleTable) {
        log.info("" + rT.hashCode());
    }
    if(ruleTable.contains(r)) {
        log.info("Hash found!");
    } else {
        log.info("Hash not found!");
    }
    return ruleTable.contains(r);
}
```

The log messages indicate that the hash of the `Rule` object (`r.hashCode()`) is `-1313430269`, and that one hash in the `HashSet` (`rT.hashCode()` in the loop) is also `-1313430269`. 
But `ruleTable.contains(r)` always returns `false`. What am I doing wrong?

I have found similar questions on StackOverflow, but these mostly involve the `equals()` or `hashCode()` methods not being (correctly) overridden. I think I have implemented this two methods correctly.

Comment: And does rT.equals(r)?

Comment: Your test uses `int` whereas your code uses `short`. Are you sure the objects aren't using `int`s and you are comparing using `short`s?

Comment: your test uses the same instances of Pool, are you sure equals works well on Pool?

Comment: You have an extra condition in equals this.getSrcTcp() == r.getSrcTcp() which is not part of hash code - maybe thats the issue, hashcode is same, but equals is false

Comment: @6ton: That's allowed...

Comment: It would really help if you'd post a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem...

Comment: Yep. Your `Rule.equals()` depends on the `equals()` for `Pool` and for whatever `getProtocol()` returns, and we can't see the code for those. (Or for the `get*()` methods, for that matter, but I'm assuming those are simple `return <field>;` getters.) Trim the example down to enough to reproduce the problem in code you can post completely.

Comment: btw, once you figure out your problem, you may want to revise how you implemented your `hashCode()` method.  Concatenating strings to calculate a hashcode is more expensive than it needs to be. Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113511/best-implementation-for-hashcode-method) for other ideas.

Comment: @JonSkeet I posted code in the answer to prove

Comment: @JonSkeet you are correct, it is allowed. But 6ton's observation is also correct, that the hashcode() method's implementation is leading the OP astray. There is a discrepancy in the OP's thought process, and the discrepancy between hashcode() and equals() illuminates it. Code must do more than satisfy the minimum requirements of the language in order to be considered good.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom: To be considered good, I agree - but I'd rather find the cause of the initial problem first, to get to code which *works*, then improve it. (Red, green, refactor FTW...)

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers! 6ton pointed me to the right direction. I'd like to "ignore" srcTcp in the lookup in the ruleTable for now, so I did not included srcTcp in the hashCode()-method. But now I see it too: the equals()-method will fail, even if the hash value is the same, which will return false for the contains()-method.

Sorry for wasting your time!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `hashCode()` and `equals()` do **not** agree.

Your `hashCode()` implementation is based on the `toString()` of the pool, but your `equals()` uses `.equals()` of the pool class.

Change your `.equals()` to compare the strings used to generate the hash code.

Answer (score 0):

There are some possibilities:

- `Rule` is mutable, after adding a rule to the set some key (w.r.t. hash or equals) field was changed;
- If two objects are equal they should have the same hashCode;
- Bug, like a comparison in `equals` using `==` i.o. `equals`.

Here I would guess you have two `Pool` instances without equals on pool name or hashCode on pool name.

Answer (score -1):

You have an extra condition in equals this.getSrcTcp() == r.getSrcTcp() which is not part of hash code - maybe thats the issue, hashcode is same, but equals is false. Check if this field is different in the values you are comparing.

Inspite of comments, I think the reason this does not work is because the equals & hashCode implementations do not use the same fields.

Code to simulate the problem:

```
import java.util.HashSet;

/**
 * @author u332046
 *
 */
public class HashCodeCollisionTest {
    public static class KeyDemo {
        String id;

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            /*if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            KeyDemo other = (KeyDemo) obj;
            if (id == null) {
                if (other.id != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
                return false;
            return true;*/
            return false;
        }

        public KeyDemo(String id) {
            super();
            this.id = id;
        }
    }

    static HashSet<KeyDemo> set = new HashSet<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        set.add(new KeyDemo("hi"));
        set.add(new KeyDemo("hello"));

        System.out.println(set.contains(new KeyDemo("hi")));
    }
}
```

This prints `false`. Uncomment the equals  code and it prints `true`

Comment: You haven't proved what you think you've proved. Your `equals` method *always* returns `false`, so obviously it's never going to print "true". A better test would be to uncomment all of the code in `equals`, but make `hashCode()` return 0 - so the same value for *all* instances.

Comment: Also read the documentation for `Object.hashCode`: "It is *not* required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hash tables."

Comment: I was trying to make a point that both need to be congruent. HashMap.getEntry does check for equality `if (e.hash == hash &&
                ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))`

Comment: No, they don't. It's always valid to return 0 from `hashCode()` for example - that's always a valid but inefficient implementation. It's entirely valid (although unusual) for `hashCode()` to check fewer fields than `equals`. The reverse is not true.

Comment: Well, its valid but pointless for any practical purpose. I haven't really seen a real world case where you would want them to behave differently

Comment: I find this funny, because you are both right and wrong.  You are wrong that both `equals` and `hashCode` need to be calculated based on the exact same list of fields (@Jon Skeet is 100% in the right, as usual).  And yet, it could very well be that you are right that the differing fields are what's causing OP to scratch his head in disbelief.  But it wouldn't be because `HashSet` is doing something wrong. It would be because perhaps OP is making the incorrect assumption that having equal `hashCodes` automatically means that the `HashSet.Contains()` check will return true.

Comment: @6ton: Suppose you have a field where computing a decent hash code might be very expensive, but equality checks are usually cheap - and where instances very rarely differ by *only* that field. In that case, it would make sense not to include it in the hash code.

Comment: @sstan I am not saying they **must** be calculated based on same fields, but practically they should be and 99.99% of the time are. When they are not it results into this discussion :)