# Java nested loops prevent duplicate

Tags: java, loops

This object is a pack of gum. Every gum is of a unique kind. We set up a pack that can hold 12 gums. We populate the pack with new gum objects. We must check the pack to see if this kind of gum has already been put in the pack. Each gum in the pack must be of a unique kind.

```
public PackOfGum()
{
  pack = new Gum[12];
  // Successfully populate pack with gum
  for (int i=0; i<12; i++) {
    pack[i] = new Gum();


    // Failure preventing duplicate gums. Idea is to look in the pack
    // at all of the gums that came before this one, and see if this one
    // matches any of them. While yes and it is a duplicate, then choose
    // a new gum.
    for (j=0; j<i; j++) {
      while (pack[i] == pack[j]) {
        pack[i] = new Gum();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm failing to correctly check all of the previous gums and compare them to the current gum. How should this be done properly?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly. But if you just want to store a non duplicate collection of guns then you can use java.util.Set for storing it. You will need to implement the equals method in the Gum class for defining the equality condition.

Comment: A  question: how do you compare Gum objects? using its memory address or its value?

Comment: what is the definition of "kind" of gum? You are now comparing if two Gum reference is referring to same Gum object instance. Given that you are creating a new Gum instance for every element in the array, it will always be different.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide your own implementation of `equals()` in your `Gum class`.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) 
{
    if (!(other instanceof GumClass))
    {
        return false;
    }
    GumClass that = (GumClass) other;
    // Custom equality check here.
    return this.field1.equals(that.field1)
     && this.field2.equals(that.field2);
}
```

You should also override `hashCode()` if there's any chance of your objects being used in a hash table. A reasonable implementation would be to combine the hash codes of the object's fields with something like:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() 
{
    int hashCode = 1;
    hashCode = hashCode * 37 + this.field1.hashCode();
    hashCode = hashCode * 37 + this.field2.hashCode();
    return hashCode;
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113511/best-implementation-for-hashcode-method) for more details on implementing a hash function

Comment: @Hector Implementing `hashCode` without implementing `equals` doesn't break the contract.  Although it is kind of silly.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things missing from your question.  For one thing, since you haven't given us the `Gum` class, I can't figure out how each `new Gum()` is going to create a unique `Gum`.  Does `Gum` have some kind of `flavor` instance variable that gets initialized to a random flavor?  Maybe, but you haven't given us that info.  Also, as the other answer points out, using `==` to compare gums isn't going to work.  Assuming that each `Gum` has a `flavor`, you will need to provide an `equals()` method that compares the `flavor` fields for equality (and a `hashCode` function that returns the same hash value for any `Gum` objects with the same flavor).

The problem I most wanted to point out was the flaw in your loop logic.  You're going through the array of existing `Gum` objects, and whenever you find a duplicate, you create a new `Gum`.  That won't get the job done.  Suppose your array consists of flavors A, B, C, D, E.  Suppose your `new Gum()` generates a gum with flavor C.  You go through the array, and you find that it matches `pack[2]`.  So you generate another `Gum`--say your random `Gum` generator generates a `Gum` with flavor B.  Now your loop won't find it, since you're still going forward through the array, and you will only be looking at D and E.  So you'll end up with a duplicate in your pack.

So what do you do?  One option is that whenever you find a duplicate, you generate a new `Gum` and then start over at the beginning of the array.  That's a pretty slow way to do things, but it will work.  Some better options:

- Maintain a `Set` of all the `Gum`'s that are already in the pack.  Now instead of going through the array to see if a `Gum` is a duplicate, just see if the set contains it.  If you use a `HashSet`, you'll be able to do this test in constant time instead of searching through an array.  (If you use a `HashSet`, you will definitely need a working `hashCode` function.)
- Keep an array of all the `Gum` flavors that haven't been used.  If you start with 12 flavors, then the first `new Gum()` will use a random number from 0 to 11, the second will use a random number from 0 to 10, the third from 0 to 9, and so on.  Each time, you will use the array and the random number to choose the right flavor, then do a swap to move that flavor to the end of the array.  For example, if the array starts out A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L and your random number is 4, that's flavor E, and you swap that with L to make your array A,B,C,D,L,F,G,H,I,J,K,E.  The next random number only goes from 0 to 11, so it won't pick E.  Whatever it does pick, you swap that with K.  And so on.