# List of Objects to be Unique

Tags: java

I have a simple class called Stock the code is listed below, and I my requirement is to create a Collection of Stock where the combination of the fields StockId, Code and name should be unique, I am doing this by implementing my own list class. I was wondering if there is any better way to do this

```
public class Stock {

    private Integer stockId;
    private String stockCode;
    private String stockName;

    public Stock() {
    }

    public Stock(Integer stockId,String stockCode, String stockName) {
        this.stockCode = stockCode;
        this.stockName = stockName;
    }



    public Integer getStockId() {
        return this.stockId;
    }

    public void setStockId(Integer stockId) {
        this.stockId = stockId;
    }

    public String getStockCode() {
        return this.stockCode;
    }

    public void setStockCode(String stockCode) {
        this.stockCode = stockCode;
    }

    public String getStockName() {
        return this.stockName;
    }

    public void setStockName(String stockName) {
        this.stockName = stockName;
    }


}
```

List class

```
public class StockList {

    private List<Stock> listStock;


    public StockList(){
        listStock =  new ArrayList<Stock>();
    }

    public void add(Stock stock){
        boolean result=true;
        for(Stock st:listStock){
            int count=0;
            if(st.getStockId()==stock.getStockId()){
                count++;
            }
            if(st.getStockCode()==stock.getStockCode()){
                count++;
            }
            if(st.getStockName()==stock.getStockName()){
                count++;
            }
            if(count>=3){
                result=false;
                break;
            }

        }
        if(result) {
            listStock.add(stock);

        }


    }

    public List<Stock> getList(){

        return listStock;
    }
}
```

I have even tried the Hashset per instructions but it still let me add two Stock objects with same values in every field

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Stock {

    private Integer stockId;
    private String stockCode;
    private String stockName;

    public Stock() {
    }

    public Stock(Integer stockId,String stockCode, String stockName) {
        this.stockCode = stockCode;
        this.stockName = stockName;
    }



    public Integer getStockId() {
        return this.stockId;
    }

    public void setStockId(Integer stockId) {
        this.stockId = stockId;
    }

    public String getStockCode() {
        return this.stockCode;
    }

    public void setStockCode(String stockCode) {
        this.stockCode = stockCode;
    }

    public String getStockName() {
        return this.stockName;
    }

    public void setStockName(String stockName) {
        this.stockName = stockName;
    }


    public int hashCode() {
        final int PRIME = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = PRIME * result + stockId+stockCode.hashCode()+stockName.hashCode();
        return result;
    }


    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        final Stock other = (Stock) obj;
        int count=0;
        if (stockId == other.stockId){
            count++;
        }
        if(stockCode.equalsIgnoreCase(other.stockCode)){
            count++;
        }
        if(stockName.equalsIgnoreCase(other.stockName)){
            count++;
        }
        if(count<3) {
            return true;
        }
    return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: consider using Set. 
Provide "equal" function to you template parameter.

Comment: Don't forget, if you override equals, you should override hashCode. ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Answer (score 6):

You will need to add your `Stock` objects in a `HashSet<Stock>`.

Before adding a `Stock` object to the set, you will be able to check whether the `HashSet` already contains it by invoking `myStockHashSet.contains( stock )`.  (But even if you go ahead and add a duplicate `stock` object to the `HashSet`, the new object will *not* replace the old object, so there will never be duplicates.)

In order for `HashSet` to work, it has to be able to tell whether two `Stock` objects are identical.  For this, your `Stock` class will need to implement `hashCode()` and `equals()`.

- `hashCode()` will need to hash together the fields `stockId`, `code` and `name`.  Recent versions of java offer an `Objects.hashCode( Object ... )` convenience method for quickly hashing together your fields.  If you are not programming against a recent version of java, you will need to write your own implementation of a `hashCode()` calculation.  Look here for some good advice: [Best implementation for hashCode method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/113511/773113)
- `equals()` should return `true` only if all these fields are equal in both objects.

NOTE:

- do *not* waste your time with a `List`, since lists allow duplicates.
- do *not* waste your time implementing `Comparable`, since this is for *ordering* objects, *not* for comparing objects for equality, *and* `HashSet` does not care whether your objects implement `Comparable`.

Comment: You don't to call `contains()` before adding, since `add()` itself will tell you if it was new.

Comment: @shmosel yes, you are right.  I added a note in the answer to that effect.

Comment: @Andreas The new object will *not* replace the existing one, so there is no difference.