# Java + can I use ConcurrentHashMap to handle 100k concurrent request?

Tags: java

I am developing the custom i18N library. in that, I have developed one function for getting locale object as per as input country and language.
I don't want to initialize locale object for every request. Can I use `ConcurrentHashMap` to store Locale objects? Can `ConcurrentHashMap` handle 100k concurrent requests?

Comment: On what hardware do you intend to generate 100,000 concurrent requests to a CHM? In any case, there's no limit to the number of concurrent requests it can handle.

Comment: What matters is not the number of concurrent request in absolute terms, but per unit of time: is it 100k per second? per minute? per day?

Comment: @ Marko Topolnik it will be used in web server. So hardware will be dedicated web server.

Comment: @assylias it can be random. the request will be varies depending on web services call from users.

Comment: That was a rhetorical question. The point is that there _won't_ be 100,000 concurrent CHM method invocations.

Comment: I am storing locale objects in static ConcurrentHashmap to reuse it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you use **a version of Java older than 8**, if you want to maximize the concurrency level of a `ConcurrentHashMap`, you need to:

1. Create your instance of `ConcurrentHashMap` with the constructor [`ConcurrentHashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor, int concurrencyLevel)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#ConcurrentHashMap(int,%20float,%20int)) in order to set the `concurrencyLevel` corresponding to the total amount of segments to use knowing that by default it is 16 and choose it wisely as using a significantly higher value than what you need can waste space and time, and a significantly lower value can lead to thread contention.
2. Implement the method `hashCode()` of your key properly in order to distribute your entries the best you can over the different segments.

In **Java 8**, the implementation of an `ConcurrentHashMap` has completely been reviewed such that you don't have segments anymore, the `concurrencyLevel` is now used as a sizing hint nothing more so #1 is no more really needed but #2 is still a good practice.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113511/best-implementation-for-hashcode-method

Answer (score 0):

ConcurrentHashMap is a very effictient data structure. You can start with it, and measure/test performance to ensure it is sufficient for you.

Comment: I've not used jMeter. I would start with generating fake requests and profile app using jmc or jvisualvm