# HashSet says it doesn't contain an element although equals returns true

Tags: java

```
class Node{
    int x, y, value;
    Node(int x, int y, int v) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        value = v;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        Node n = (Node)o;
        boolean result = this.x == n.x && this.y == n.y && this.value == n.value;
        return result;
    }
}

void test() {
    HashSet<Node> s = new HashSet<>();
    Node n2 = new Node(1, 1, 11);
    Node n1 = new Node(1, 1, 11);
    s.add(n1);
    System.out.println(s.contains(n2));
    System.out.println(n1.equals(n2));
}
```

returns:

> false
>
> true

Per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains-java.lang.Object-, HashSet uses equal to judge if it contains an element. So shouldn't the contains call return true here? What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: You have to override `hashCode()` too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the javadoc for [Object.equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)):

*Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes.*

That is what is missing in your class! This [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113511/best-implementation-for-hashcode-method) can give you some ideas how to hashCode() your class.

Answer (score 3):

The 1st thing that comes to my eye is that you are overriding equals in an inappropriate way. You are not considering, comparing reference, null object or class itself.

something like this is missing in your equals method:

```
if (this == obj)
    return true;
if (obj == null)
    return false;
if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
    return false;
```

On the other hand, you have to implement correctly the contract for the Node class: i.e. you need to override equals **AND hashCode** too

Answer (score 0):

I will explain you on WHY to override `hashcode()`, for this, basically you need to understand how `HashSet` works.

First thing is because you are NOT overriding the `hashcode()`, your `Node` class will get the default implementation from `java.lang.Object` class.

You can add a `System.out.println` and print the hashcodes of both of the `Node` objects in your `equals()` as shown below:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    Node n = (Node)o;
    //Add System.out.println to check the hashcodes
    System.out.println(n.hashCode()+"::::::"+this.hashCode());

    boolean result = this.x == n.x && this.y == n.y && this.value == n.value;
    return result;
}
```

You can check the output by running the above method, you will see that **the hashcodes are different for both objects i.e., this proved that the two objects are equal but their hashcodes are different**.

Now coming to the `hashSet.contains(n2)`, how `HashSet` works is that **it stores the objects into different buckets based on their hashcodes**. So **your two `Node` objects will fall under two different buckets and `contains()` will return `false`**.

So, to summarise, the rule is that **the equal objects must have equal hash codes**, so you always need to override `hashcode()` along with your `equals()` so that you will not get the contradictory results like the above `equals()` and `contains()`