# Why should I have to call/initialize the hashCode() method for each member of a class?

Tags: java, collections, hashcode

I noticed in examples of `hashCode()`, everyone is using the same fields to call `hashCode()` inside the `hashCode()` method definition.

Why should I have to call/initialize the `hashCode()` method  for each member of a class, as hash code is for the finding the object location (correct me if i am wrong)?

So what is the purpose of calling the `hashCode()` inside the `hashCode()` method definition.

For example:

```
public int hashCode() {
    final int seed = 37;
    int result = 1;
    result = seed * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    result = seed * result + age;
    result = seed * result + marks;
    return result;
}
```

Here we have two fields `age` and `name`. What is the purpose of **`name.hashCode()`**  on line no 4.

Comment: See also: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode-- reusing the hashCode is common practice because it will follow the contract for that field. But nobody forces you to do so. `age` is probably an int - so you cannot call hashCode() on it ...

Comment: Ok. i got the point. But my question is why???

means why we need to call hashCode() over the non primitive members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hashCode` method is used by collections like `HashMap` and `HashSet` to distribute your object's instances in a way that they will be fast to retrieve (with a time complexity of `O(1)`). The better is your `hashCode` method implemented, the more efficient would be those collections when used with your object's instances. A well implemented `hashCode` method would limit as much as possible the probability to get hash collisions, in other words, it would limit the possibility to get the same hash code for 2 different object's instances.

Knowing that, if we remove the line #4 from your `hashCode`'s implementation, we would then have **all** the object's instances with the same `age` and `marks` that would have **the same** resulting hash code whatever the value of `name` so the probability to get hash collisions is high which is not wanted as explained above.

So since `hashCode` returns a `32` bits integer and `name` is obviously a `String` (at least not a primitive type), we call `hashCode()` on it to get an `int` representation of the `String` in order to add somehow its value to the resulting hash code. Thanks to that, 2 object's instances with the same `age` and `marks` won't have necessarily the same hash code, the risk of getting hash collisions is limited which is what we expect.

Comment: Thank you so much @Nicolas Filtto

This is what i want to know. i ll never forget the reason for using hashCode() for non primitive type. your answer is very helpful to understand.!!

Answer (score 1):

I think a more generic form of this question has already been asked -

[Best implementation for hashCode method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113511/best-implementation-for-hashcode-method)

To summarise it for your question, "name" is a String object and "age" is an int literal. The seed value is usually a prime number.