# Java how to make the hash unique

Tags: java, generics, hash, interface, hash-code-uniqueness

I'm trying to create an abstract class Coin, having instance variables name (a String), symbol (of type java.awt.Image), and hash (a String.) The problem is that I need to make the attribute hash not the same as the one being returned by the default hashcode() method, hence having the hash of a Coin unique.

```
abstract class Coin {

    private String name;
    private Image symbol; 
    private String hash;

}
```

Comment: A hash code is not a `String`. You could always try something of the form `return name.hashCode()+symbol.hashCode()`, but it is of the essence of hash codes that they are *not* unique. There are no [tag:generics] here.

Comment: hash computing should be designed (coded) in the same philosophy like `equals()` - this is comparison to be equal. Hash can be duplicate - equals() tell the true

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113511/best-implementation-for-hashcode-method - Check this out. Explains a good methodology for creating your own hash

Comment: @EJP Yes you are right hash code is not a String, however in this specific assignment I'm required to make the hash a String and have the hash of a Coin unique. Well I might have interpreted wrongly the implementation of the assignment, but I would love to see the way you would implement it. (ps sorry for the sloppy code but I'm a beginner)

Comment: assignment 'unique hash' is incorrect. I dont know, this is school (poor understanding), or industry (XY problem)

Comment: For uniqueness, you need an UUID (basically a large random number), not a hash.

Comment: @JacekCz It's a university assignment and the teacher mentioned that "the hash of a Coin is unique." I just didn't know how to implement it, because he can also refer to the class name which is Coin.

Comment: You need to post the background material. A hash code is *not* a `String`, whatever you were told: it is a number.

Comment: @EJP I've added the assignment description above, if that helps.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can override the default `hashCode()` function in the following way:

```
 @Override
public int hashCode() {
    // Unique hashcode generating function goes here
    return hash;
}
```

A way could be using `name.hashCode()+symbol.hashCode()`.

Comment: mathematics say, such hash has poor statistic parameters - but technically is OK

Comment: generally, hashCode() method is very poor for uniquness the collision is very frequent.

Comment: @nafas Rubbish. It depends *entirely* on how the method is written. You cannot make blanket statements like that about a mere method signature.

Comment: @EJP hashCode() returns an int so the number of combinations is bound to 32bits. even MD5 (supposed to be insecure nowadays) got 128bits,

Answer (score 0):

before I move on just let you know, a hash value may never be 100% unique because of [hash collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_(computer_science)).

having said that, I assume you want a unique String for variable hash(note `hashCode()` function in java is different as it returns an int)

there are many hashing algorithms, the one I normally use for unification in such scenario is [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5)

There is an **Apache utility** called [DiguestUtility](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html) which make life easy.

Here is an example of the use:

```
DigestUtils.md5(byte[] bytes);// --> returns a string of 32 char long
DigestUtils.md5(String s);// --> returns a string of 32 char long
...
```

Read through the methods in the documentation to see which one suits you more.