# Duplicate key in HashMap in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, hashmap

I am creating a JSP shopping basket, I have a class called Basket which has a HashMap with a Product object as a key and Integer for values, which will be the quantity of the product. However when I add a product to the basket, instead of that product's quantity being incremented, the product is just added again into the map. The hashcode of the product changes, but the product I add is the same object, they do not change. I would like to understand what is happening here.

Basket class add method:

```
   public void addItem(String pid) {
        addItem(db.getProduct(pid));
    }

    public void addItem(Product p) {
        if (p != null) {
            Integer quantity = items.get(p);
            if (quantity == null){
                quantity = 1;
                System.out.println("first time adding");
            }
            else quantity++;

            items.put(p, quantity);
            System.out.println("added product: " + p + " with quantity of " + quantity);
        }
    }
```

Basket.JSP:

```
<%@ page import="shop.Product" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.HashMap" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Map" %>
<jsp:useBean id='basket'
             scope='session'
             class='shop.Basket'
/>
<%
    String empty = request.getParameter("emptyBasket");
    if (empty != null) {
        basket.clearBasket();
        System.out.println("basket cleared");
    }
    String item = request.getParameter("addItem");
    basket.addItem(item);
%>
<html>
<body>
<% HashMap<Product, Integer> items = basket.getItems();

    for (Map.Entry<Product, Integer> p : items.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(p.getKey().hashCode() + " " + p.getValue());
    }
%>
```

in viewProduct.JSP I have a link containing

```
href="basket.jsp?addItem=<%=product.PID%>
```

to get to the basket page.

So my main question is why is the map adding the same key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely need to implement a `hashCode` method in the `Product` class.

By default the `hashCode` implementation returns the object's location in memory.  The result from the object's `hashCode` method is what is used by the `HashMap` to identify the object.

In this case each time the `Product` is retrieved from the database using `db.getProduct(pid)`, its location in memory is likely different.

Due to this the call that `HashMap` uses to lookup if the `Product` exists is different and therefore the object is added again to the `HashMap`.

To avoid this a `hashCode` and `equals` method should be implemented in `Product`.  In your case using something unique like the ProductID (`pid`) makes sense:

```java
// Assuming pid is public
public int hashCode() {
  return this.pid;
}

public equals(Object object) {
  return this.pid == ((Product)object).pid;
}
```

For more info on how to implement a more-robust `hashCode` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/113600/9129020