# @override hashcode() in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I’ve read about hash and HashMap coming from here: https://howtodoinjava.com/java/collections/hashmap/design-good-key-for-hashmap/

In particular:

```
//Depends only on account number
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + accountNumber;  
    return result;
}
```

Why the hash code is calculated with `prime * result + accountNumber` and not only from `accountNumber`

What meaning has the fixed value prime * result? 
Why not just prime (result value is 1 so prime time 1 is prime)?

Answer (score 1):

Code generation uses that in order in the case of *multiple* fields to have randomness:

```
result = prime * result + accountNumber;  
result = prime * result + hairColorAsInt; // Biometrics to identify account
result = prime * result + userWeight;
```

So indeed unneeded, but here it might serve a purpose: accountNumber should never leak to the outside if possible, hence duplicating it into the hashCode is undesirable. I do not know of any serialisation storing the hashCode, so it is a weak argument.

Answer (score 0):

Citing [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/113600/6803997), a prime number is necessary to ensure all value combinations of fields in an object create distinct and unique hash codes. Yes, this may not be necessary when you only have a single `int` for fields, but as soon as you want to add any, you would need to change your implementation to the above source; this is of course not desirable, and the solution works in all use cases, so it may as well be used from the beginning.