# Converting LREAL to binary and interpreting it as base 10 LINT

Tags: codesys, structured-text

Running "CODESYS V3.5 SP16" here, I am trying to implement the hashcode algorithm mentioned in

[Best implementation for hashCode method for a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113511/best-implementation-for-hashcode-method-for-a-collection/113600#113600)

and had to built my own solution to replicate Java's `Float.floatToIntBits(f)` which resulted in the following function

```
FUNCTION F_lrealToLintBits : LINT
VAR_INPUT
  lrVal : LREAL;
END_VAR
VAR
  arrBytes : ARRAY[0..7] OF BYTE; // LREAL contains 64 bits and each byte contains 8 bits
  pVal     : POINTER TO LREAL := ADR(arrBytes);
  diIndx   : DINT;
  uiExpt   : UINT := 0; // exponent goes from 0 to 63
END_VAR
```

```
pVal^ := lrVal; // maps LREAL to array of bytes

// little endian? cause it seems that least significant bit is at lowest address
FOR diIndx := LOWER_BOUND(arrBytes, 1) TO UPPER_BOUND(arrBytes, 1) BY 1 DO
  // bit access seems to be manual only so no loops
  IF arrBytes[diIndx].0 THEN
    F_lrealToLintBits := F_lrealToLintBits + LREAL_TO_LINT(EXPT(2, uiExpt));
  END_IF

  uiExpt := uiExpt + 1; // have to increment exponent after every bit

  IF arrBytes[diIndx].1 THEN
    F_lrealToLintBits := F_lrealToLintBits + LREAL_TO_LINT(EXPT(2, uiExpt));
  END_IF

  uiExpt := uiExpt + 1; // have to increment exponent after every bit

  IF arrBytes[diIndx].2 THEN
    F_lrealToLintBits := F_lrealToLintBits + LREAL_TO_LINT(EXPT(2, uiExpt));
  END_IF

  uiExpt := uiExpt + 1; // have to increment exponent after every bit

  IF arrBytes[diIndx].3 THEN
    F_lrealToLintBits := F_lrealToLintBits + LREAL_TO_LINT(EXPT(2, uiExpt));
  END_IF

  uiExpt := uiExpt + 1; // have to increment exponent after every bit

  IF arrBytes[diIndx].4 THEN
    F_lrealToLintBits := F_lrealToLintBits + LREAL_TO_LINT(EXPT(2, uiExpt));
  END_IF

  uiExpt := uiExpt + 1; // have to increment exponent after every bit

  IF arrBytes[diIndx].5 THEN
    F_lrealToLintBits := F_lrealToLintBits + LREAL_TO_LINT(EXPT(2, uiExpt));
  END_IF

  uiExpt := uiExpt + 1; // have to increment exponent after every bit

  IF arrBytes[diIndx].6 THEN
    F_lrealToLintBits := F_lrealToLintBits + LREAL_TO_LINT(EXPT(2, uiExpt));
  END_IF

  uiExpt := uiExpt + 1; // have to increment exponent after every bit

  IF arrBytes[diIndx].7 THEN
    F_lrealToLintBits := F_lrealToLintBits + LREAL_TO_LINT(EXPT(2, uiExpt));
  END_IF

  uiExpt := uiExpt + 1; // have to increment exponent after every bit
END_FOR
```

Firstly, I would like to know if there is an existing function in some library that does this already?

I looked in many places including in the OSCAT "Basic, 3.31" library but could not find anything similar (even a set of functions that I could chain together would be OK).

Secondly, can bit access only be done manually?

I would prefer to use a loop but it seems that is not possible? Is there a less copy-and-paste method of accessing the bits that would involve automatically detecting the number of bits if the data type in the array changes from `BYTE` to something else (e.g. `DWORD`)?

### Potential alternative

Seems like this is where unions come in handy, as mentioned in https://forge.codesys.com/forge/talk/Engineering/thread/02a65a50b2/#e5f4/1911/c524 where if the value does not come from an external source (i.e. no need to check for endian-ness), `Float.floatToIntBits(f)` would be as simple as

```
TYPE
  U_lrealToRawLintBits :
  UNION
    lrVal : LREAL;
    liVal : LINT;
  END_UNION
END_TYPE
```

```
// supposed to replicate floatToIntBits() in Java at
// https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/739769c8fc4b496f08a92225a12d07414537b6c0/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Float.java#L775
FUNCTION F_lrealToLintBits : LINT
VAR_INPUT
    lrVal : LREAL;
END_VAR
VAR
    uLrealToLintBits : U_lrealToRawLintBits; // for interpreting LREAL as base 10 LINT
END_VAR
```

```
IF FPU.IsLRealPosInfinity(lrVal) THEN
  F_lrealToLintBits := 2139095040; // corresponds to 0x7f800000
ELSIF FPU.IsLRealNegInfinity(lrVal) THEN
  F_lrealToLintBits := 4286578688; // corresponds to 0xff800000
ELSIF FPU.IsLRealNaN(lrVal) THEN
  F_lrealToLintBits := 2143289344; // corresponds to 0x7fc00000
ELSE
  uLrealToLintBits.lrVal := lrVal;
  F_lrealToLintBits := uLrealToLintBits.liVal;
END_IF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to achieve is to take as input an LREAL but with the bits inside really being those of a LINT, but byte-swapped.

If so, there should be a more straightforward solution.  Here is an example :

```
FUNCTION lreal_to_int64 : LINT
VAR_INPUT
  value: LREAL;
  value_is_little_endian: BOOL;
END_VAR
VAR
  no_swap: BOOL;
  source_bytes, target_bytes: POINTER TO BYTE;
  value_as_lint: POINTER TO LINT;
END_VAR

{IF defined (IsLittleEndian)}
  no_swap := value_is_little_endian;
{ELSE}
  no_swap := NOT value_is_little_endian;
{END_IF}

IF
  no_swap
THEN
  value_as_lint := ADR(value);
  lreal_to_int64 := value_as_lint^;
  RETURN;  
END_IF

target_bytes := ADR(lreal_to_int64);
source_bytes := ADR(value);
target_bytes[0] := source_bytes[7];
target_bytes[1] := source_bytes[6];
target_bytes[2] := source_bytes[5];
target_bytes[3] := source_bytes[4];
target_bytes[4] := source_bytes[3];
target_bytes[5] := source_bytes[2];
target_bytes[6] := source_bytes[1];
target_bytes[7] := source_bytes[0];
```

Programmatic access to bits is certainly possible using bitwise operators.  Try something like this.

```
FUNCTION get_bit : BOOL
VAR_INPUT
  value: LWORD;
  bit_position: USINT;
END_VAR
VAR
 shifted: LWORD;
END_VAR

shifted := SHR(value, bit_position);
get_bit := shifted.0;
```

Comment: your solution is definitely far more elegant, didn't even know about the `IsLittleEndian` operator before